# Grafana is not loading data from local Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

I was recently introduced to Elastic Search (ES) and Grafana. I have to make a Grafana dashboard to display data from Elastic Search.

I installed ES locally, created the index the same way it was created in a production server. I also inserted some documents for testing. Then I installed Grafana locally as well and added two datasources: a remote ES instance we have and my local ES instance as well.

Then I started with a very basic query just to show a table listing a single property. **This query works and returns data in the remote server**, but it does not work when I change the database to my local server.

As I'm pretty new to this stack I don't even know what kind of information would be useful to help me, so I'm pasting below the content of the query inspector. Also my question is if someone has tips on what could be causing it and tips to solve.

Thanks for any help

```
{
   "xhrStatus":"complete",
   "request":{
      "method":"POST",
      "url":"api/datasources/proxy/1/_msearch?max_concurrent_shard_requests=5",
      "data":"{\"search_type\":\"query_then_fetch\",\"ignore_unavailable\":true,\"index\":\"event_tracking_3\"}\n{\"size\":0,\"query\":{\"bool\":{\"filter\":[{\"range\":{\"datetime\":{\"gte\":\"1579083211126\",\"lte\":\"1579104811127\",\"format\":\"epoch_millis\"}}},{\"query_string\":{\"analyze_wildcard\":true,\"query\":\"*\"}}]}},\"aggs\":{\"2\":{\"terms\":{\"field\":\"type.keyword\",\"size\":10,\"order\":{\"_key\":\"desc\"},\"min_doc_count\":1},\"aggs\":{}}}}\n"
   },
   "response":{
      "took":1,
      "responses":[
         {
            "took":1,
            "timed_out":false,
            "_shards":{
               "total":1,
               "successful":1,
               "skipped":0,
               "failed":0
            },
            "hits":{
               "total":{
                  "value":0,
                  "relation":"eq"
               },
               "max_score":null,
               "hits":[

               ]
            },
            "aggregations":{
               "2":{
                  "doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,
                  "sum_other_doc_count":0,
                  "buckets":[

                  ]
               }
            },
            "status":200
         }
      ],
      "$$config":{
         "method":"POST",
         "url":"api/datasources/proxy/1/_msearch?max_concurrent_shard_requests=5",
         "data":"{\"search_type\":\"query_then_fetch\",\"ignore_unavailable\":true,\"index\":\"event_tracking_3\"}\n{\"size\":0,\"query\":{\"bool\":{\"filter\":[{\"range\":{\"datetime\":{\"gte\":\"1579083211126\",\"lte\":\"1579104811127\",\"format\":\"epoch_millis\"}}},{\"query_string\":{\"analyze_wildcard\":true,\"query\":\"*\"}}]}},\"aggs\":{\"2\":{\"terms\":{\"field\":\"type.keyword\",\"size\":10,\"order\":{\"_key\":\"desc\"},\"min_doc_count\":1},\"aggs\":{}}}}\n"
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Forget it =] It's the time range of the query. 
I'm answering just to be useful to someone else facing the same "issue".